# Can we create a Sugar CRM Application Account (Not the CRM Account) using Web Services?

Tags: sugarcrm

We are working on integrating with a SugarCRM instance running community edition. Just to let users of our web application manage their contacts. Below is what we are trying to achieve;

a) Each user once he has Signed Up, our application will create a SugarCRM Application Account for them using Web Services.
b) The user can then add leads & contacts through our tool.

I know b) can be done easily using the Web Services, is there a way for me to do a)?

Looking forward for responses. I can share more details (if needed).

Comment: If you are still looking for Customer Self Service Portal, take a look at our product here. SugarCRM responsive customer support portal | Urdhva Tech Pvt.Ltd.

Comment: ...but the CE edition of SugarCRM do not support for Customer Self Service Portal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, we decided not to move forward with that.